# "Non mais tu vois l'humour que je donne?" Has anybody heard this ( except in Orne, Basse Normandie)?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, régionalismes

I've already heard in Orne (Basse Normandie) a guy saying, at the end of some sentences "tu vois l'humour que je donne?" in a way similar to "tu vois" , "you know what I mean".

I suspect that this is an expression coming from the 70's.

I wonder whether this expression has already been fashionable all over France, or whether it is proper to Orne (département 61).

Comment: I have never heard that expression.

Comment: jlliagre. Neither did I before I went to Orne....

Comment: I have never been in the Orne, outside crossing it by train but that didn't gave me a chance to hear the locals ;-)

Comment: @RayLittleRock are you refering to the whole sentence, or just the "tu vois" part ?

Answer (score 1):

I know some people (between 50 and 80 years old) who are from Orne. They've never heard that before and I also asked my parents who are from Vendée and Lorraine and they are the same. It may not help you but it replies to the first question haha!

But I'm pretty sure this expression is not popular in France even in Normandie and is definitely not fashionable here in France.

Comment: @purestamp.Thanks for your research! :)

Comment: @RayLittleRock No worries it was a pleasure.. oh and my mother told me this expression sounds very weird ^.^ Bu thank **you** to introduce such as a not common expression !

Comment: If it is not even poplar in Orne, it may be self-invented. Some people invent words or expressions, which become part of their character. Some of these words or expressions become famous. I doubt this one will.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard that expression but I have already heard expressions that are similar :

- *Tu vois (bien)* -> "You perceive" (I have never heard *to perceive* before, thanks to Google translate!)
- *Tu vois (bien) ce que je veux dire* -> "You know what I mean"

Comment: *Tu vois* can simply be translated by *you see* in both sentences. In any case, the question is about ***l'humour que je donne***, not *tu vois*.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be very short: I have never heard (nor read) anything like that in my whole life. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16021)

Comment: @Toto The question is "Has anybody heard this?" I answer, as a 46 native French speaker, that I haven't and, to the extent of my knowledge, no,  this is extremely rare. No critique nor request of clarification involved.

Comment: Certes, mais cette réponse gagnerait à être un peu étoffée, telle quel c'est plus un commentaire qu'une réponse.

Comment: @Toto OK, je comprends ce point de vue, je prendrai garde à développer mes réponses à l'avenir.